# Django - Complex query

Tags: python, django

Assuming I have two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    #some fields here

class Ratings(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(profile)
    category = models.IntegerField()
    points = models.IntegerField()
```

Assuming following examle of MySQL table "ratings":

```
profile    |    category    |    points
   1                1               10
   1                1               4
   1                2               10
   1                3               0
   1                4               10
   1                4               10
   1                4               10
   1                5               0
```

I have following values in my POST data and also other fields values:

```
category_1_avg_val = 7
category_2_avg_val = 5
category_3_avg_val = 5
category_4_avg_val = 7
category_5_avg_val = 9
```

I want to filter profiles that have the average ratings calculated for categories higher or equal to required values.

Some filters are applied initially as:

```
q1 = [('associated_with', search_for),
      ('profile_type__slug__exact', profile_type),
      ('gender__in', gender),
      ('rank__in', rank),
      ('styles__style__in', styles),
      ('age__gte', age_from),
      ('age__lte', age_to)]
q1_list = [Q(x) for x in q1 if x[1]]

q2 = [('user__first_name__icontains', search_term),
      ('user__last_name__icontains', search_term),
      ('profile_type__name__icontains', search_term),
      ('styles__style__icontains', search_term),
      ('rank__icontains', search_term)]
q2_list = [Q(x) for x in q2 if x[1]]

if q1_list:
    objects = Profile.objects.filter(
        reduce(operator.and_, q1_list))

if q2_list:
    if objects:
        objects = objects.filter(
            reduce(operator.or_, q2_list))
    else:
        objects = Profile.objects.filter(
            reduce(operator.or_, q2_list))

if order_by_ranking_level == 'desc':
    objects = objects.order_by('-ranking_level').distinct()
else:
    objects = objects.order_by('ranking_level').distinct()
```

Now i want to filter profiles whose (average of points) (group by category) >= (avg values of category coming in post)

I tried to do this one by one as

```
objects = objects.filter(
    ratings__category=1) \
    .annotate(avg_points=Avg('ratings__points'))\
    .filter(avg_points__gte=category_1_avg_val)


objects = objects.filter(
    ratings__category=2) \
    .annotate(avg_points=Avg('ratings__points'))\
    .filter(avg_points__gte=category_2_avg_val)
```

But this is wrong I think. Please help me out. If return is a queryset that would be great.

**Edited**
Using the answer posted by `hynekcer` I came up with slightly different solution as I have already queryset of profiles which needs to be filtered more based on rating.

```
def check_ratings_avg(pr, rtd):
    ok = True
    qr = Ratings.objects.filter(profile__id=pr.id) \
        .values('category')\
        .annotate(points_avg=Avg('points'))
    qr = {i['category']:i['points_avg'] for i in qr}

    for cat in rtd:
        val = rtd[cat]
        if qr[cat] >= val:
            pass
        else:
            ok = False
            break
    return ok


rtd = {1: category_1_avg_val, 2: category_2_avg_val, 3: category_3_avg_val,
       4: category_4_avg_val, 5: category_5_avg_val}
objects = [i for i in objects if check_ratings_avg(i, rtd)]
```

Comment: I think that the names of classes (models Profile and Ratings) should be capitalized as is usual in Django. Othervise the name of field `profile` can be easy confused by the same name of model.

Comment: yes u r right, actually the class names are capitalize in my models.py file. Jst forgot to do that here. Any ideas about acuall problem?

Comment: Your suggested second solution added by editing can be very slow if the first "black box" filter would select millions of profiles. Running millions of SQL queries is a nightmare. The most as possible should be done by one queryset. Please, what you can say about the first "black box" filter? Is it based only on one table (Profile) or on more? Can it be written only by more `filter` and `exclude` type conditions, eventually also with Q and F object conditions, but without any aggregation function? Please describe the type of these additional restrictions in your question.

Comment: @hynekcer i have updated my question please check the blackbox filters in `some filters are applied initially as:` section of question. As you see if user only go for `free text search` the `q1_list` will be empty and there will be many profiles. And if `q2_list` will be used then there will be less profiles. but still not sure  how many profiles will be there. So the most optimum solution is required.

Comment: `Conditional Annotations` i'm missing you :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your complex query require a subquery in the principle. Possible solutions are:

- A *subquery* written by ['extra' queryset method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#extra) or [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/) query. It is not DRY and it was unsupported by some db backends, e.g. by some versions of MySQL, however subqueries are by some limited way used since Django 1.1.
- Saving intermediate results into a temporary table in the database. It is not nice in Django.
- Emulation of the outer query by loop in Python. The best universal solution. A loop in Python over database data aggregated by the first query can aggregate and filter the data fast enough.

**A) Subquery emulated by Python**

```
from django.db.models import Q, Avg
from itertools import groupby
from myapp.models import Profile, Ratings

def iterator_filtered_by_average(dictionary):
    qr = Ratings.objects.values('profile', 'category', 'points').order_by(
            'profile', 'category').annotate(points_avg=Avg('points'))
    f = Q()
    for k, v in dictionary.iteritems():
        f |= Q(category=k, points_avg__gte=v)
    for profile, grp in groupby(qr.filter(f).values('profile')):
        if len(list(grp)) == len(dictionary):
            yield profile

#example
FILTER_DATA = {1:category_1_avg_val, 2:category_2_avg_val, 3:category_3_avg_val,
               4:category_4_avg_val, 5:category_5_avg_val}
for row in iterator_filtered_by_average(FILTER_DATA):
    print row
```

This is a simple solution for the original question without later additional requirements.

**B) Solution with subqueries**:
It is necessary for the more detailed version of question because if the initial filters are based on some field of type `ManyToManyField` and also because it contains a `distinct` clause:

```
# objects:  QuerySet that you get from your initial filters. Not yet executed.
if rtd:
    # Method `as_nested_sql` removes the `order_by` clase, unlike `as_sql`
    subquery3 = objects.values('id').query \
            .get_compiler(connection=connection).as_nested_sql()
    subquery2 = ("""SELECT profile_id, category, avg(points) AS points_avg
          FROM myapp_ratings
          WHERE profile_id in
          ( %s
          ) GROUP BY profile_id, category
            """ % subquery3[0], subquery3[1]
    )
    where_sql = ' OR '.join(
            'category = %d AND points_avg >= %%s' % cat for cat in rtd.keys()
    )
    subquery = (
        """SELECT profile_id
        FROM
        ( %s
        ) subquery2
        WHERE %s
        GROUP BY profile_id
        HAVING count(*) = %s
        """ % (subquery2[0], where_sql, len(rtd)),
        subquery2[1] + tuple(rtd.values())
    )
    assert order_by_ranking_level in ('asc', 'desc')
    mainquery = ("""SELECT myapp_profile.* FROM myapp_profile
      INNER JOIN
      ( %s
      ) subquery ON subquery.profile_id=myapp_profile.id
      ORDER BY ranking_level %s"""
        % (subquery[0], order_by_ranking_level), subquery[1]
    )
    objects = Profile.objects.raw(mainquery[0], params=mainquery[1])
return objects
```

Replace please all strings `myapp` by `name_of_your_application`.

Example of SQL generated by this code

```
SELECT myapp_profile.* FROM myapp_profile
  INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT profile_id
    FROM
    ( SELECT profile_id, category, avg(points) AS points_avg
      FROM myapp_ratings
      WHERE profile_id IN
      ( SELECT U0.`id` FROM `myapp_profile` U0 WHERE U0.`ranking_level` >= 4
      ) GROUP BY profile_id, category
    ) subquery2
    WHERE category = 1 AND points_avg >= 7 OR category = 2 AND points_avg >= 5
       OR category = 3 AND points_avg >= 5 OR category = 4 AND points_avg >= 7
       OR category = 5 AND points_avg >= 9
    GROUP BY profile_id
    HAVING count(*) = 5
  ) subquery ON subquery.profile_id=myapp_profile.id
  ORDER BY ranking_level asc
```

(This SQL is for better readability parsed manually with strings `%s` replaced by parameters, however the database engine receive parameters unparsed for security reasons.)

---

Your problem is due to little support of subqueries generated by Django. Only examples from documentation of more complicated queries create a subquery. (e.g. `aggregate` after `annotate` or `count` after `annotate` or `aggregate` after `distinct`, but no `annotate` after `distinct` or after `annotate`) Complicated nested aggregations are simplified to one query which is unexpected.

All other solutions that execute a new individual SQL query for every object filtered by the first query are discouraged for production although they can be very useful for testing results of any better solution.

Comment: How good is in terms of efficiency `Emulation of outer query by loop in python`?? Considering 5 million records in `Profile` table and 5*5 million rows in `Rating` table?

Comment: The speed depends on values of parameters `category_*_avg_val`, which affects much the selectivity of individual conditions (e.g. you select mostly 90% or 10% of profiles?) and on typical number of ratings for one profile (little more than one or hundreds ratings for profile). It is better to compare both emulated and raw query solutions on expected data. (Not much straightforward for me than for you now. I deleted the test application a few hours ago.)

Comment: Actually this query will come in search engine, so i have to select all the profiles who follows all the parameters. I have done it slightly differently from your approach as i have filtered queryset of Profiles already which i need to filter more.

Comment: Please check my updated question, i added a solution, but i don't know how much it will effect the efficiency.

Comment: Obviously I will choose your answer if I didn't get any best solution :)

Comment: Aamir@ I rewrote the solution for your task. It is fast if you have enough memory relative to data: Tested for 100000 profiles with random number of 0..2 ratings i.e. 500000 ratings: It takes 0.6 second with filter with parameters selecting 11000 profiles on my notebook with default MySQL settings. The time is then quadratically proportional to size of data. For really big data it is useful to add some cached precomputed data that can be easy updated, e.g. sum of points and count of ratings for (profile, category) in order to prevent many aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

You could add methods to a manager

```
# Untested code
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def with_category_average(self, cat, avg):
        # Give each filter a unique annotation key
        key = 'avg_pts_' + str(cat)
        return self.filter(ratings__category=cat) \
                   .annotate(**{key: Avg('ratings__points')}) \
                   .filter(**{key + '__gte': avg})

    # Expects a dict of `cat: avg` pairs
    def filter_by_averages(self, avg_dict):
        qs = self.get_query_set()
        for key, val in avg_dict.items():
            qs &= self.with_category_average(key, val)
        return qs
```

Comment: although your code has some errors, but i tested it, this same as doing annotation one by one as i mentioned in my question. The problem is that in this manner the queryset will be evaluated separately for each category, i need to AND all the categories together.

Comment: This line `qs.with_category_average(key, val)` should be `self.with_category_average(key, val)`

Comment: well, that was supposed to be the AND you're speaking of, but I see that I am too much used to my ChainableManagers. How about this version with `&=`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is still yielding wrong results, objects which are not supposed to be in queryset are still coming :(

Comment: When a profile meets condition >= for all 5 categories of rating then it should be present in queryset, if any category average does not meet with the condition >= it should be excluded, which is not happening at the moment

Comment: i think the bug is: suppose for first iteration func `with_category_average` returns a querset, but in second iteration it returns `[]` the `&=`will still contains the profile object from first iteration

Comment: I do believe `query_set & empty_query_set` should yield `empty_query_set`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19125/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-jesse-the-game)